# Change the camera position of GMS Map View with animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried to zoom in and zoom out the GMSCamera but failed to perform this with animation. I can have gone through the documentation as well. but nothing helped.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    let zoom = GMSCameraUpdate.zoom(to: 15.0)
    self.mapView.animate(toZoom: zoom)
}
```

The above code does not animate the mapview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code. You may update it for latest swift syntax.

```
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(58.998400,longitude: 10.035604, zoom: 1)


    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(2.0, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    let city = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(58.998400,longitude: 10.035604, zoom: 15)
    self.mapView.animateToCameraPosition(city)
    CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Hi Amrit Thanx Man. You save my day.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `UIView.animate` on google map as google map has its own method to animate with zoom level.

You just need to call this method.

```
let lat = 21.78841 //latitude of the location to display on map
let lng = 72.25478 //longitude of the location to display on map
let camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng), zoom: 17)
 mapView.animate(to: camera)
```

From Google's Doc.

```
/** Animates the camera of this map to |cameraPosition|. */
- (void)animateToCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)cameraPosition;
```